# How to databind a property on a custom user control?

Tags: asp.net

I have a custom user control `UserProfileLink` on which I have two basic string properties, `UID` and `UserFullName` which I would like to use in a template column in a DataGrid like this:

```
....
<ItemTemplate>
  <td:UserProfileLink ID="uplUser" runat="server" UID="<%#Eval("UserUID") %>" UserFullName="<%#Eval("UserFullName") %>" />
</ItemTemplate>
....
```

I get an error saying "The server tag is not well formed" which leads me to believe this type of binding isn't possible. Is there a way to do this, or is it impossible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try ' instead of " for the server tag

`<td:UserProfileLink ID="uplUser" runat="server" UID='<%#Eval("UserUID") %>' UserFullName='<%#Eval("UserFullName") %>' />`